# Conditional statement / If statement with Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to assign a value to column 'Percentage' based on multiple columns 'Class' and 'Value'

Below is a link that has my dataframe:
https://filebin.net/fo2wk7crmwf0fycc

This is the logic that I want to be applied:

```
If df['Class'] equals 2 or 3, and if df['Value'] is less than 0.5, set df['Percentage'] to 0
If df['Class'] equals 2 or 3, and if df['Value'] is > 0.5 and <= 0.7, set df['Percentage'] to 0.25
If df['Class'] equals 2 or 3, and if df['Value'] is > 0.7 and <= 0.9, set df['Percentage'] to 0.5
Else set df['Percentage'] to 1
```

Below is an example of the output I am looking for:

| Class | Value | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.01 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.6 | 0.25 |
| 3 | 0.9 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use pure [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like below:

```
import numpy as np    
df['Percentage'] = np.where((df['Class'].isin([2, 3]) & (df['Value'] <= 0.5)), 0, 
                            np.where((df['Class'].isin([2, 3]) & (df['Value'] > 0.5) & (df['Value'] <= 0.7)), 0.25,
                                np.where((df['Class'].isin([2, 3]) & (df['Value'] > 0.7) & (df['Value'] <= 0.9) ), 0.5, 1)))
```

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is just like if-then-else conditional statement which you can easily understand.

```
       Class     Value  Percentage
0          2  0.000620         0.0
1          2  0.000620         0.0
2          3  0.001240         0.0
3          4  0.000620         1.0
4          5  0.000620         1.0
...      ...       ...         ...
14782      5  0.001178         1.0
14783      2  0.001116         0.0
14784      3  0.001178         0.0
14785      5  0.000310         1.0
14786      5  0.001116         1.0

[14787 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

#### Numpy and `searchsorted`

When using `searchsorted` you don't need to include the boundaries like `0` and `1` in this case.

```
bins =  np.array([.5, .7, .9])
labels = np.array([0, .25, .5, 1])
cut = bins.searchsorted(df.Value)
results = labels[cut]

df.assign(Percentage=np.where(df['Class'].isin([2, 3]), results, 1))

       Class     Value  Percentage
0          2  0.000620         0.0
1          2  0.000620         0.0
2          3  0.001240         0.0
3          4  0.000620         1.0
4          5  0.000620         1.0
...      ...       ...         ...
14782      5  0.001178         1.0
14783      2  0.001116         0.0
14784      3  0.001178         0.0
14785      5  0.000310         1.0
14786      5  0.001116         1.0

[14787 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

#### Pandas `cut`

When using `pd.cut` you **DO** need the boundaries because Pandas will create intervals.

```
#                        / boundaries \
#                       ↓              ↓
cut = pd.cut(df.Value, [0, .5, .7, .9, 1], labels=[0, .25, .5, 1])

df.assign(Percentage=np.where(df['Class'].isin([2, 3]), cut, 1))

       Class     Value  Percentage
0          2  0.000620         0.0
1          2  0.000620         0.0
2          3  0.001240         0.0
3          4  0.000620         1.0
4          5  0.000620         1.0
...      ...       ...         ...
14782      5  0.001178         1.0
14783      2  0.001116         0.0
14784      3  0.001178         0.0
14785      5  0.000310         1.0
14786      5  0.001116         1.0

[14787 rows x 3 columns]
```